# Using cypress-testrail-accumulative-reporter

Tags: testing, automated-tests, cypress, coded-ui-tests, testrail

I've set cypress-testrail-accumulative-reporter to use on my project.
But the testrun that is created each time contains ALL existing in testrail cases.
What I need it's created test run with only a regression set.
For example, I have 1000 cases and only 10 are regression.
When I enter `npx cypress run` test run with ONLY 10 cases should be created and populated with results, not 1000.

Can you pls help me with this?

```
"reporter": "cypress-testrail-accumulative-reporter",
  "reporterOptions": {
  "domain": "domain",
  "username": "name",
  "password": "pass",
  "projectId": 1,
  "suiteId": 1,
  "allowFailedScreenshotUpload": true,
  "runName": "Regression"
```

Answer (score 1):

By default, `npx cypress run` will run all tests headlessly.

You must use `npx cypress run --spec "<LIST OF SPECFILES>"` to execute your specific tests.

e.g. `cypress run --spec "cypress/integration/examples/actions.spec.js,cypress/integration/examples/files.spec.js"`

Please take a look at https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/command-line#cypress-run for further details about cypress run.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I know how to run specific cases, but how to create TestRun in TestRail automatically ONLY with these cases? Currently my TestRun contains ALL tests from TestRail even not automated in cypress.